# Why are there two SCSS rules in Webpack 2 config ejected by Angular CLI

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-2

I have ejected our webpack configuration with Angular CLI, and I am wondering why there are two rules for processing SCSS.

```
{
    exclude: [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/styles.scss"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/vendor.scss")
    ],
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [
        "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
        "css-loader",
        "postcss-loader",
        "sass-loader"
    ]
},
{
    include: [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/styles.scss"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/vendor.scss")
    ],
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: [
            "css-loader",
            "postcss-loader",
            "sass-loader"
        ],
        fallback: "style-loader",
        publicPath: ""
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is for global stylesheets and one is for component stylesheets. The first rule is for component styles, because it's *excluding* the global styles, and the second one is for global styles, as it's *including* the global styles. `include` and `exclude` are mutually exclusive. `include` means "only these", while `exclude` means "all but these"

Both these stylesheet types are handled differently. Generally the component styles will be compiled inline, while the global styles will be injected into the HTML `<style>` element